# How to allow NULL in foreign keys of a compound primary key

Tags: postgresql, schema, foreign-key, primary-key, null

I want to have `NULL`s in foreign keys of a compound primary key. This is an example of what I would expect to be **valid** data.

| product_id | variant_id |
| --- | --- |
| 123-123 | ABC |
| 123-123 | NULL |
| 456-456 | ABC |

I cannot figure out why the following SQL in postgres gives `NOT NULL` violation constraint me when inserting `NULL` as `variant_id`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS inventory.price (
  product_id             UUID NOT NULL, -- this has to be always to a valid product
  variant_id             UUID,          -- this could be NULL
  amount                 MONEY NOT NULL,
  created_at             TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  -- Constraints
  CONSTRAINT inventory_price_pkey PRIMARY KEY (product_id, variant_id),
  CONSTRAINT inventory_price_inventory_product_fkey FOREIGN KEY (product_id)
    REFERENCES inventory.product (id) MATCH FULL,
  CONSTRAINT inventory_price_inventory_variant_fkey FOREIGN KEY (variant_id)
    REFERENCES inventory.variant (id) MATCH SIMPLE,
  CONSTRAINT inventory_price_amount_gt_0 CHECK (amount > '0'::money)
);
```

And the inspection to `information_schema` confirms the non-nullable constraint.

| column_name | column_default | is_nullable | data_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| product_id | NULL | NO | uuid |
| variant_id | NULL | NO | uuid |
| amount | NULL | NO | money |
| created_at | now() | NO | timestamp with time zone |

Comment: Personally I think your DB design is wrong. You basically have a conditional join (either `product` or `variant`) you should have every `product` have at least one `variant` and join only on that

Comment: @Charlieface the reason is that a price could be for the "base" product, thus without variant. Having a variant describing a base product (thus not actually varying the base product) is conceptually wrong imo

Comment: I suppose another way of describing it is that the `price` relates to a `product, variant` pair, for which `variant` could be null. But then you have no table which maps a `product, variant` relation with a null `variant`, only ones with extant `variant`s. Because you can't have a nullable primary key, you would need a `variant_id` for such a row anyway. So it's not wrong to say that there are `product`s having any number of `variant`s, that number may be one.

Comment: @Charlieface I am not sure to understand what you mean by "no table which maps a product, variant relation with a null variant, only ones with extant variants". What I am currently thinking of using is a table with the relation you described: `price` has a partial unique index for `product, variant` so that `variant` can be null and can be assigned once per `product`. A base `product` can have a `price` which is represented by the `variant` begin null. Using the `price` table, I can join `product, variant` and get a list of `variants`'s `product` and viceversa.

Comment: Yes but you can't use it as a primary key, because by definition a primary key cannot be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the primary key constraint enforces the not null constraint. You can look at the following [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5024936bf25e9781bd0ab0cc52c49a17)

I'm not sure what it is that you want to achieve. Should the following be valid:

```
INSERT INTO price (product_id, variant_id, ...
VALUES ('123-123', null, ...)
     , ('123-123', null, ...)
```

? If not (i.e. only one allowed null varant per product), you can use a generated column and add the constraint there:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS price3 (
  product_id             UUID NOT NULL, -- this has to be always to a valid product
  variant_id             UUID,          -- this could be NULL
  variant_ext_id         UUID NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS (COALESCE(variant_id, product_id)) STORED,
  amount                 MONEY NOT NULL,
  created_at             TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  -- Constraints
  CONSTRAINT inventory_price_pkey3 PRIMARY KEY (product_id, variant_ext_id),
  CONSTRAINT inventory_price_amount_gt_03 CHECK (amount > '0'::money)
);
```

You would, of course, need to apply that rule in any dependent tables. From a normalisation point of view, you may want to treat products and variant of products differently.

Other things that come to mind is to use a default value such as:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS price (
  product_id             UUID NOT NULL, -- this has to be always to a valid product
  variant_id             UUID DEFAULT '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' NOT NULL,
  amount                 MONEY NOT NULL,
  created_at             TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  -- Constraints
  CONSTRAINT inventory_price_pkey PRIMARY KEY (product_id, variant_id),
  CONSTRAINT inventory_price_amount_gt_0 CHECK (amount > '0'::money)
);
```

Edit: Another option is to change the primary key to a unique constraint, see [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=dd4f2bcb01ec2c0d645009745a38eeb8):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product (
  product_id UUID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

insert into product values ('33a9fb48-5c0c-4bec-a1d9-382a73856e53');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS price (
  product_id             UUID NOT NULL, -- this has to be always to a valid product
  variant_id             UUID,          -- this could be NULL
  amount                 MONEY NOT NULL,
  created_at             TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  -- Constraints
  CONSTRAINT inventory_price_pkey UNIQUE (product_id, variant_id),
  CONSTRAINT inventory_price_inventory_product_fkey FOREIGN KEY (product_id)
    REFERENCES product (product_id),
  CONSTRAINT inventory_price_amount_gt_0 CHECK (amount > '0'::money)
);

insert into price (product_id, amount)
values ('33a9fb48-5c0c-4bec-a1d9-382a73856e53','12');

insert into price (product_id, variant_id ,amount)
values ('33a9fb48-5c0c-4bec-a1d9-382a73856e53', '33a9fb48-5c0c-4bec-a1d9-382a73856e54', '19');


CREATE TABLE example ( 
  product_id             UUID NOT NULL,
  variant_id             UUID,
  foreign key (product_id) references product (product_id),
  foreign key (product_id, variant_id) references price (product_id, variant_id)
);


-- valid, f.k. evaluates to Null
insert into example (product_id)
values ('33a9fb48-5c0c-4bec-a1d9-382a73856e53');

-- valid, f.k. evaluates to True
insert into example (product_id, variant_id)
values ('33a9fb48-5c0c-4bec-a1d9-382a73856e53', '33a9fb48-5c0c-4bec-a1d9-382a73856e54');

-- invalid, f.k. evaluates to False
insert into example (product_id, variant_id)
values ('33a9fb48-5c0c-4bec-a1d9-382a73856e53', '33a9fb48-5c0c-4bec-a1d9-382a73856e55');
```

Comment: I tried the above approaches, but I felt that the `variant_ext_id` was a sort of hack and the "defaults" approach implies that I have a default empty variant `000000-....` which is not clean as well. Ended up by using an auto generated ID and an `UNIQUE` constraint on the two foreign keys.

Comment: You don't need the generated id, i'll add an explanation to my answer

Comment: Other than that, I agree that all in my answer is "hacks". But, most of the time I would say that generated id's belong in that category as well.

Comment: I don't get the purpose of the `example` table. In the last context, how would I insert the data for the table mentioned in the question?

Comment: The example table is just any child table of price. It demonstrates that there is no need for the generated id in price. Not sure what you mean with the table mentioned in the question, I thought that where `price` and my example already contains two inserts into that table

Comment: Yes you are right, completely missed them. I will have a deeper look and I will have some tests locally. Once I find out, will come back here for a feedback. Many thanks!

Comment: I updated the example at: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=33d20e8d4408457f7dc3eaf0df250135  It also includes the one benefit of a generated id that I can think of

Comment: The solution with `variant_ext_id UUID NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS (COALESCE(variant_id, product_id)) STORED,` is exactly what I was looking for. It worked perfectly, thanks! No duplicated tuples.

Comment: Just mark the answer as accepted. It will inform future readers that there is a solution to your problem

Answer (score 1):

After different attempts, as `PRIMARY KEY`s cannot have `NULL`s values of any sort, the most simple and effective approach was to generate an ID and use a `UNIQUE` constraint on the two foreign keys.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS inventory.price (
  id                     UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
  product_id             UUID NOT NULL,
  variant_id             UUID,
  amount                 MONEY NOT NULL,
  created_at             TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  -- Constraints
  CONSTRAINT inventory_price_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT inventory_price_inventory_product_fkey FOREIGN KEY (product_id)
    REFERENCES inventory.product (id) MATCH FULL,
  CONSTRAINT inventory_price_inventory_variant_fkey FOREIGN KEY (variant_id)
    REFERENCES inventory.variant (id) MATCH SIMPLE,
  CONSTRAINT inventory_price_product_variant_unique UNIQUE (product_id, variant_id),
  CONSTRAINT inventory_price_amount_gt_0 CHECK (amount > '0'::money)
);
```